# Ubuntu 23.04 MySQL Workbench CTD - Gtk-CRITICAL Errors

Tags: mysql, crash, gtk, mysql-workbench

**System Information**

Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
GTK 3.24.37-1ubuntu1

KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-26-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11

---

I have Installed latest Mysql and is working

Downloaded and Installed Latest MySQL Workbench community_8.0.34-1ubuntu23.04_amd64.deb
(Also crashes with SNAP version)

MySQL Launches and I can setup a database connection
When I edit a small EER Model of 4 tables, it crashes to desktop after a few edits. Adding table columns, foreign Keys etc, although its not predictable.

---

**Launching from the Command Line I get the following warning on startup**
(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:14:42.012: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1649:16: '-gtk-icon-size' is not a valid property name

(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:14:42.012: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1652:16: '-gtk-icon-size' is not a valid property name

---

> **I get the following error when it Crashes**

(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:14:49.771: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:14:49.789: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:16:14.028: gtk_cell_layout_get_area: assertion 'GTK_IS_CELL_LAYOUT (cell_layout)' failed

(mysql-workbench-bin:2929): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:16:14.028: gtk_cell_area_get_edit_widget: assertion 'GTK_IS_CELL_AREA (area)' failed
/usr/bin/mysql-workbench: line 108:  2929 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin "$@"

I learned this could be due to using a theme that MySQL-Workbench doesnt like so have tried resetting the desktop to its default state with
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme

but it still keeps crashing with the above error

I was using MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 22.04.01 with no problems. Is there a way I can fix this? Or do I need to reinstall the old version of Ubuntu to get it going?

Thanks